# App terminates due to uncaught exception "Issue with Classes"

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am learning Object C and I can not figure out why I am getting the following error:

```
2013-01-08 21:46:12.984 ObjectiveCDemo[38355:c07] -[Calculator subtractFromTotal:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7568c90
2013-01-08 21:46:12.985 ObjectiveCDemo[38355:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Calculator subtractFromTotal:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7568c90'
```

I am creating a simple app that does calculator function. Code I am using is:

```
    calculator = [[Calculator alloc] init];
    double sum = [calculator addToTotal:10];
    double difference = [calculator subtractFromTotal:6];
    double results = [calculator multiplyTimesTotal:3];
    double quotient = [calculator divideFromTotal:4];
    [calculator clear];

    NSLog(@"Sum: %f", sum);
    NSLog(@"Difference: %f", difference);
    NSLog(@"Results: %f", results);
    NSLog(@"Quotient: %f", quotient);
```

Error happens on the double difference line.  I can comment out that line and the NSlog line that references it and the program runs fine.  Example of the calculator class is:

```
- (double) addToTotal:(double)value{total += value;
return total;}

- (double) subtractfromTotal:(double)value{total -= value;
return total;}

- (double) multiplyTimesTotal:(double)value{total *= value;
return total;}

- (double) divideFromTotal:(double)value{total /= value;
return total;}
```

While this error has been mentioned before, I can't see how any of the other solutions apply

Answer (score 1):

Your method name doesn't match the way that you called it.

Calling code:

```
double difference = [calculator subtractFromTotal:6];
```

Implementation:

```
- (double) subtractfromTotal:(double)value
```

Should be:

```
- (double) subtractFromTotal:(double)value
```

The compiler undoubtedly warned you about this. You should pay attention to compiler warnings! They are usually telling you something important!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Error log carefully and you can see this line

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Calculator subtractFromTotal:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7568c90'
```

it clearly tells you that you are trying to send a message with `subtractFromTotal:(double)value` while you have implemented it with `subtractfromTotal:(double)value`. Pay attention to the error log.